# Access variables that are set in page level JSP, in data-sly-use javascript of components in AEM HTL?

Tags: aem, sightly, htl

In a page level component I have set a variable.

```
<c:set var="stepIndex" value="-1" scope="page"/>
```

Now I author a few component on the page. These components should have access to the stepIndex variable. The components are written in HTL and I want to access 
stepIndex inside data-sly-use Javascript api.

How can I achieve this ?

I can do this using JSP scriplets using request. GET and SET attributes but I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page context is a JSP-specific implementation and HTL cannot access it. In order to share data between different servlets/scripting engines you should use the request scope. You can set the value with `<c:set var="stepIndex" value="-1" scope="request"/>` and then retrieve it with `request.getAttribute("stepIndex")`

Comment: Retreived it in my component's WCMUsePojo using request.getAttribute('stepIndex')